# Component renders undefined if user refreshes page if no data from props.history is passed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have a doughnut chart component where a user can click the element. onClick, I pass the pathname and id to another component which will render a table. This works fine, however, I need to figure out what happens if a user decides to refresh the second component. Currently, if a user refreshes, it throws an error of undefined because we did not pass any props.

How would I solve this issue if a user decides to refresh the page?

```
//doughnut component that will pass data

import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

  onDonutClick = item => {
    try {
      this.props.history.push({
        pathname: "/component that will receive the id",
        state: { id: item[0]._index }
      })
    } catch(error) {
      console.log(error)
    }
  }

export default withRouter(DoughnutComponent);
```

```
//table component that will recieve the data

import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: [some table data in here],
      index: "",
      sourceData: []
  }

  componentDidMount = () => {
    this.getTableData();
  }

  getTableData = () => {
    let id = this.props.history.location.state.id;
    if(id === 6) {
      this.setState({
        index: 6,
        sourceData: this.state.data
      })
    } else {
      const tData = this.state.data.filter(function(item){
        return item.id === id;
      })
      this.setState({
        index: id,
        sourceData: tData
      })
    }
  }
```

I have tried the below. id of 6 will show the whole table.

```
if(!this.props.history.location.state.id) {
  this.setState({
   index: 6,
   sourceData: this.state.data
  )} else {
    let id = this.props.history.location.state.id;
    if(id === 6) {
      this.setState({
        index: 6,
        sourceData: this.state.data
      })
    } else {
      const tData = this.state.data.filter(function(item){
        return item.id === id;
      })
      this.setState({
        index: id,
        sourceData: tData
      })
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: you can have two approaches either add the needed part like id in the url so even user refresh you can get from url params, second one is even the user refresh you can store it in react router state , this.props.history.push({state: 1}), so after refresh also you can take the id from the state inside the react route so you can access as         {this.props.location.state.id}. Let me know this helps you so will add it as an answer

Comment: @DILEEPTHOMAS will approach #1 work if a user decides to navigate directly to the url? Do you have an example I could see for both approaches? I'm having a hard time envisioning the approaches you mentioned.